# How to read the value printing inside a jsp (as a custom HTML tag) onChange event in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am using the following to read the image from local system and try converting the same into base64 using moxie.

```
<a id="file-picker" href="javascript:;"></a>
```

Base 64 result is printing inside code

```
<code id="result"> Result is printing here</code>
```

I need to access the result(Base 64 value) in Js:

```
 $("#file-picker").on('change',function(event){
var tmppath ;
tmppath = $("#code").val();
```

How do I read the base 64 value printed inside the  in JS on change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the internal data from `<code></code>` using **`.html()`**

```
$("#file-picker").on('click',function(event){

    var tmppath = $("#result").html();

}
```

And you should bind **`click`** event on anchors and not **`change`** event